# An iOS app want to play flash video

Tags: ios, flash

My app supports playing videos, but some of them are in Flash format. How can I make my app to support Flash playback? Thank you.

Comment: Are you making your app with Flash or Swift or Objective-C?? iOS only supports H264 video placed inside a MP4 file. If your FLV files also contain H264 codec for the video part you can simply extract per frame from FLV and re-package bytes as MP4 then send to video-decoder. How are you making the app (programming language), Can you handle bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is currently no way to support the Flash format on iOS except [through a proxy browser like Photon](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/photon-flash-player-for-ipad/id430200224?mt=8), which works like remote desktop.

If you must include your Flash videos, you can consider converting them to MP4.

Comment: But the Flash format (FLV) is a media container that supports all mp4 codecs (except h265). You can put H.264 video and also AAC or MP3 audio into a FLV file. He simply needs to extract that frame data from FLV and put into some temporary bytes in MP4 style. If iOS allows for directly sending the AAC/H.264 directly to the iOS system to play then even better. No need for tricky MP4 bytes re-packaging.